# How to use variable across two forms in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, variables, button, splash-screen

Hi I currently have a splash screen with a 'play' button which generates a random number and loads up a new form. In this form I wish to use the random number that is generated in the splash screen but I am unsure how to use it in both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for sharing variables across forms in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451340/best-practice-for-sharing-variables-across-forms-in-vb-net)

Comment: You can declare your variable/s as `Public Shared` or put it/them in a `Module`

Comment: @lemaggot, you should show us what you have tried till now. Anyway, AlexM. suggestion is correct.