# How do I get the data of datagridview per row and show it in the textboxes in the ANOTHER FORM? VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have two forms. One is the **Main.vb** which the ***datagridview*** is located and the other one is the **EditPage.vb** which consist a set of ***textboxes***. If I click a row in ***datagridview*** and click the ***edit button*** in the ***datagridview*** in **Main.vb** it will go in **EditPage.vb**. Then, the data of the ***clicked row*** will show in the **textboxes in EditPage.vb**... I'll try to **public my variables** and set it in the other **form(EditPage.vb)** but still the data of the selected row didn't shown up. What's something wrong in my code **even it has no error?**

Here's the code of my ***datagridview Cell Content Click*** in **Main.vb**

```
Private Sub tblAttendance_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles tblAttendance.CellContentClick
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = tblAttendance.CurrentRow





    Try
        id = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        firstname = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString
        lastname = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString
        birthdate = row.Cells(3).Value.ToString
        position = row.Cells(4).Value.ToString
        sex = row.Cells(5).Value.ToString
        address = row.Cells(6).Value.ToString
        contact_num = row.Cells(7).Value.ToString
        email = row.Cells(8).Value.ToString

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Input Data Properly!", "Error Message")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here's the code of my ***Edit Button*** in **Main.vb**

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Edit the Info?", "Validation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)

    If DialogResult.Yes Then

        Edit_Page.Show()

    ElseIf DialogResult.No Then
        MessageBox.Show("Edit Cancelled", "Message")

    End If

End Sub
```

And Here's my ***Public Variables*** in **Main.vb**

```
Public id As Integer
Public firstname As String
Public lastname As String
Public birthdate As String
Public position As String
Public sex As String
Public address As String
Public contact_num As String
Public email As String
```

My ***Public Variables*** in **EditPage.vb** to get the ***public variables*** in **Main.vb**

```
Public id_edit As Integer
Public firstname_edit As String
Public lastname_edit As String
Public birthdate_edit As String
Public position_edit As String
Public sex_edit As String
Public address_edit As String
Public contact_num_edit As String
Public email_edit As String
```

The code in the of the form of **Edit.Page.vb** or called  **Edit_Page_Load**

```
 id_edit = Main.id
    firstname_edit = Main.firstname
    lastname_edit = Main.lastname
    birthdate_edit = Main.birthdate
    position_edit = Main.position
    sex_edit = Main.sex
    address_edit = Main.address
    contact_num_edit = Main.contact_num
    email_edit = Main.email


    firstname_txtbox.Text = firstname_edit
    lastname_txtbox.Text = lastname_edit
    DateTimePicker1.Text = birthdate_edit
    position_txtbox.Text = position_edit
    sex_combo.Text = sex_edit
    address_txtbox.Text = address_edit
    contact_mask.Text = contact_num_edit
    email_txtbox.Text = email_edit
```

AGAIN, MY PROBLEM IS I CAN'T GET THE DATA OF THE SELECTED ROW OF MY **DATAGRIDVIEW** IN ***MAIN.VB*** AND **SHOW IT** IN **EDITPAGE.VB'S TEXTBOXES**.

Comment: Don't attach unrelated tags to your question.

Comment: @TJWolschon oops sorry about that, editing at the same time.

Comment: @JacobH Quite alright, just wanted the tags to be correct.

Comment: I might be crucified for this, but if you're planning on sharing data between these forms in this way, perhaps a separate module for shared variables is good here?

Comment: sorry, but i want to find the answer of my rare question because I never encounter this kind of problem in vb.net. I cant find an exact answer.

Comment: I mean, I don't think your question is that rare: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451340/best-practice-for-sharing-variables-across-forms-in-vb-net And using a shared module *is* an exact answer. Just like passing an instance of the main form is an exact answer (from the thread above).

Comment: `Crucifies >> Jacob` :) Jacob is actually on to something there, you have essentially written out a [Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx) . Create a `Class Employee` or similar, add in the properties as you have almost done `Public Property FirstName` .. `Public Property LastName`... etc. Then as you can build a list of `Employees` and store that in a Shared Variable, `Public Shared Employess as list (of Employee)` as you edit / change the values, these can be refreshed throughout the app. Without going into too much detail, its worth trying to get your head round!

Answer (score 0):

Declare a class (Form level) level Public variable for a binding source.

```
Public bind As New BindingSource()
```

Bind to your DataGridView

```
Private Sub FillGrid()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CoffeeConnectionString)
            Dim strSQL As String = "Select * From Coffees;"
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)
                'dr As SqlDataReader
                cn.Open()
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    dt.Load(dr)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        bind.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bind
End Sub
```

Then on the second form use the BindingSource from the first form.

```
Private Sub TestBindingSource_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtCoffeeName.DataBindings.Add("Text", ExcelToDGV.bind, "Name")
End Sub
```